# how to add event on calendar item in android

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

i tried to add  eventactivity on onclicklistener of calendar item in calendar item but i am getting null pointer exception.

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public GregorianCalendar month, itemmonth;// calendar instances.

public CalendarAdapter adapter;// adapter instance
public Handler handler;// for grabbing some event values for showing the dot
// marker.
public ArrayList<String> items; // container to store calendar items which
// needs showing the event marker
ArrayList<String> event;
LinearLayout rLayout;
ArrayList<String> date;
ArrayList<String> desc;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

    rLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.text);
    month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    itemmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();

    items = new ArrayList<String>();

    adapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, month);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(calendarUpdater);

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));

    RelativeLayout previous = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.previous);




    previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setPreviousMonth();
            refreshCalendar();
        }
    });

    RelativeLayout next = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNextMonth();
            refreshCalendar();

        }
    });

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            // removing the previous view if added
            if (((LinearLayout) rLayout).getChildCount() > 0) {
                ((LinearLayout) rLayout).removeAllViews();
            }
            desc = new ArrayList<String>();
            date = new ArrayList<String>();
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
            String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                    .get(position);
            String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
            String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                    "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
            int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
            // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
            if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

            for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                if (Utility.startDates.get(i).equals(selectedGridDate)) {
                    desc.add(Utility.nameOfEvent.get(i));
                }
            }

            if (desc.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < desc.size(); i++) {
                    TextView rowTextView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

                    // set some properties of rowTextView or something
                    rowTextView.setText("Event:" + desc.get(i));
                    rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    // add the textview to the linearlayout
                    rLayout.addView(rowTextView);

                }

            }

            desc = null;

        }

    });
}

protected void setNextMonth() {
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + 1),
                month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
    }

}

protected void setPreviousMonth() {
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
    }

}

protected void showToast(String string) {
    Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void refreshCalendar() {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    adapter.refreshDays();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    handler.post(calendarUpdater); // generate some calendar items

    title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
}

public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        items.clear();

        // Print dates of the current week
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        String itemvalue;
        event = Utility.readCalendarEvent(MainActivity.this);
        Log.d("=====Event====", event.toString());
        Log.d("=====Date ARRAY====", Utility.startDates.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
            itemvalue = df.format(itemmonth.getTime());
            itemmonth.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
            items.add(Utility.startDates.get(i).toString());
        }
        adapter.setItems(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

}

AddEventActivity.java

```
  public class AddEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private Context mContext;
private String provinceIdSend;
Spinner sp_am,sp_hh,sp_mm,sp_amed,sp_province,sp_hhed,sp_mmed,sp_states;
private RelativeLayout main;
private String stateId,selectedProvince,cityIdSend,cityId,selectedState,stateIdSend;
private ArrayList<StatesBean> statesBeanArrayList;
private ArrayList<ProvinceBean> provinceBeanArrayList;
private int countclickedState = 0;
private TextView tv_province;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_event);
    mContext = AddEventActivity.this;
    new MakeRequestForGetStates().execute();
    new MakeRequestForGetProvinces(stateId).execute();

    sp_am = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_am);
    sp_hh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_hh);
    sp_mm = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_mm);
    sp_amed = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_amed);
    sp_mmed = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_mmed);
    sp_hhed = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_hhed);
    sp_province = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_province);
    sp_states= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_states);
    tv_province= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_province);
    sp_am.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sp_hh.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sp_mm.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sp_amed.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sp_mmed.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sp_hhed.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sp_province.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sp_states.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> list_hh = new ArrayList<String>();
    list_hh.add("00");
    list_hh.add("01");
    list_hh.add("02");
    list_hh.add("03");
    list_hh.add("04");
    list_hh.add("05");
    list_hh.add("06");
    list_hh.add("07");
    list_hh.add("08");
    list_hh.add("09");
    list_hh.add("10");
    list_hh.add("11");
    list_hh.add("12");
    list_hh.add("HH");

    List<String> list_mm = new ArrayList<String>();
    list_mm.add("00");
    list_mm.add("01");
    list_mm.add("02");
    list_mm.add("03");
    list_mm.add("04");
    list_mm.add("05");
    list_mm.add("06");
    list_mm.add("07");
    list_mm.add("08");
    list_mm.add("09");
    list_mm.add("10");
    list_mm.add("11");
    list_mm.add("12");
    list_mm.add("13");
    list_mm.add("14");
    list_mm.add("15");
    list_mm.add("16");
    list_mm.add("17");
    list_mm.add("18");
    list_mm.add("19");
    list_mm.add("20");
    list_mm.add("21");
    list_mm.add("22");
    list_mm.add("23");
    list_mm.add("24");
    list_mm.add("25");
    list_mm.add("26");
    list_mm.add("27");
    list_mm.add("28");
    list_mm.add("29");
    list_mm.add("30");
    list_mm.add("31");
    list_mm.add("32");
    list_mm.add("33");
    list_mm.add("34");
    list_mm.add("35");
    list_mm.add("36");
    list_mm.add("37");
    list_mm.add("38");
    list_mm.add("39");
    list_mm.add("40");
    list_mm.add("41");
    list_mm.add("42");
    list_mm.add("43");
    list_mm.add("44");
    list_mm.add("45");
    list_mm.add("46");
    list_mm.add("47");
    list_mm.add("48");
    list_mm.add("49");
    list_mm.add("50");
    list_mm.add("51");
    list_mm.add("52");
    list_mm.add("53");
    list_mm.add("54");
    list_mm.add("55");
    list_mm.add("56");
    list_mm.add("57");
    list_mm.add("58");
    list_mm.add("59");
    list_mm.add("MM");

    List<String> list_am = new ArrayList<String>();
    list_am.add("AM");
    list_am.add("PM");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list_hh);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter_mm = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list_mm);

    dataAdapter_mm.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter_am = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list_am);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    sp_am.setAdapter(dataAdapter_am);
    sp_hh.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    sp_hhed.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    sp_mm.setAdapter(dataAdapter_mm);
    sp_amed.setAdapter(dataAdapter_am);
    sp_mmed.setAdapter(dataAdapter_mm);
    // Spinner item selection Listener


    // Button click Listener

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()) {

        case R.id.sp_states:

            String idToSendForCities = statesBeanArrayList.get(position).getStateID();
            stateIdSend = idToSendForCities;
            if (countclickedState == 1) {

                    new MakeRequestForGetProvinces(idToSendForCities).execute();

            }
            countclickedState=1;
            selectedState = sp_states.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;

        case R.id.sp_province:
            cityIdSend = provinceBeanArrayList.get(position).getCityID();
            selectedProvince = sp_province.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
private class MakeRequestForGetStates extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    private String response;

    private MakeServiceClass makeServiceClass = new MakeServiceClass();


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> parms = new HashMap<String, String>();
            response = makeServiceClass.makeServiceConnectionPost(Const.STATE_DETAILS_URL, parms);
            Log.e("response states", response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(response);

        if (response != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (mainObject.has("Status")) {

                    String Status = mainObject.getString("Status");
                    if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) {

                        if (mainObject.has("Data")) {
                            JSONArray datArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("Data");
                            statesBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            if (datArray.length() > 0) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < datArray.length(); i++) {

                                    StatesBean statesBean = new StatesBean();

                                    JSONObject internalDataObject = datArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    if (internalDataObject.has("StateID")) {

                                        statesBean.setStateID(internalDataObject.getString("StateID"));

                                    }
                                    if (internalDataObject.has("Title")) {

                                        statesBean.setTitle(internalDataObject.getString("Title"));

                                    }
                                    statesBeanArrayList.add(statesBean);

                                }

                                setStatesSpinnerdata();


                            } else {

                                showMessage("No occupations found for your profile.");


                            }

                        }

                    } else {

                        showMessage("Server error, Please try again");


                    }


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }
}

private class MakeRequestForGetProvinces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    private String response, stateIdNew;

    private MakeServiceClass makeServiceClass = new MakeServiceClass();

    MakeRequestForGetProvinces(String id) {

        this.stateIdNew = id;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> parms = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parms.put("StateID", stateIdNew);
            response = makeServiceClass.makeServiceConnectionPost(Const.GETCITIES_FORSTATE_URL, parms);
            Log.e("response cities", response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(response);

        if (response != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (mainObject.has("Status")) {

                    String Status = mainObject.getString("Status");
                    if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) {

                        if (mainObject.has("Data")) {
                            JSONArray datArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("Data");
                            provinceBeanArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            if (datArray.length() > 0) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < datArray.length(); i++) {

                                    ProvinceBean provinceBean = new ProvinceBean();

                                    JSONObject internalDataObject = datArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    if (internalDataObject.has("CityID")) {

                                        provinceBean.setCityID(internalDataObject.getString("CityID"));

                                    }
                                    if (internalDataObject.has("Title")) {

                                        provinceBean.setTitle(internalDataObject.getString("Title"));

                                    }
                                    provinceBeanArrayList.add(provinceBean);

                                }

                                setCitiesSpinnerdata();


                            } else {

                                showMessage("No province found for your profile.");


                            }


                        }


                    } else {





                    }


                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }
}
private void setStatesSpinnerdata() {

    String stateName = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < statesBeanArrayList.size(); i++) {

        if (statesBeanArrayList.get(i).getStateID().equalsIgnoreCase(stateId)) {
            stateName = statesBeanArrayList.get(i).getTitle();
            break;

        }


    }

    stateIdSend = stateId;


    ArrayList<String> allData = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!stateName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        allData.add(0, stateName);
        selectedState = stateName;
    } else {

        allData.add(0, "Select State");
        selectedState = "Select State";
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < statesBeanArrayList.size(); i++) {

        allData.add(statesBeanArrayList.get(i).getTitle());

    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allData);

    // Drop down followup_details_layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    sp_states.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


}

private void setCitiesSpinnerdata() {

    String cityName = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < provinceBeanArrayList.size(); i++) {

        if (provinceBeanArrayList.get(i).getCityID().equalsIgnoreCase(cityId)) {
            cityName = provinceBeanArrayList.get(i).getTitle();
            break;

        }
    }

    cityIdSend = cityId;
    ArrayList<String> allData = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!cityName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        allData.add(0, cityName);
        selectedProvince = cityName;
    } else {

        allData.add(0, "Select Province");
        selectedProvince = "Select Province";

    }
    for (int i = 1; i < provinceBeanArrayList.size(); i++) {

        allData.add(provinceBeanArrayList.get(i).getTitle());

    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allData);

    // Drop down followup_details_layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    sp_province.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


}
private void showMessage(String message) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(main, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();

    snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

    snackbar.show();

}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

Calendar adapter.java

```
 public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
Fragment fragment;
private java.util.Calendar month;
public GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
/**
 * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
 */
public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
int firstDay;
int maxWeeknumber;
int maxP;
int calMaxP;
int lastWeekDay;
int leftDays;
int mnthlength;
String itemvalue, curentDateString;
DateFormat df;

private ArrayList<String> items;
public static List<String> dayString;
private View previousView;

public CalendarAdapter(Context c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar) {
    CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    month = monthCalendar;
    selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
    mContext = c;
    month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
    refreshDays();
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
    for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
            items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
        }
    }
    this.items = items;
}

public int getCount() {
    return dayString.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dayString.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    TextView dayView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        viewHolder.date_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
        viewHolder.lay_cal_item = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lay_cal_item);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.lay_cal_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, AddEventActivity.class));
        }
    });

    dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    // separates daystring into parts.
    String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
    // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
    String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
    // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
    if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
        // setting offdays to white color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else {
        // setting curent month's days in blue color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
        setSelected(v);
        previousView = v;
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
    }
    dayView.setText(gridvalue);

    // create date string for comparison
    String date = dayString.get(position);

    if (date.length() == 1) {
        date = "0" + date;
    }
    String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
    if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
        monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
    }

    // show icon if date is not empty and it exists in the items array
    ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
    if (date.length() > 0 && items != null && items.contains(date)) {
        iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
class ViewHolder {
    private TextView date;
    private ImageView date_icon;
    private LinearLayout lay_cal_item;
}
public View setSelected(View view) {
    if (previousView != null) {
        previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
    }
    previousView = view;
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
    return view;
}

public void refreshDays() {
    // clear items
    items.clear();
    dayString.clear();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
    // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
    firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // finding number of weeks in current month.
    maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
    mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
    maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
    calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
    /**
     * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
     * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
     */
    pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
    /**
     * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
     */
    pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

    /**
     * filling calendar gridview.
     */
    for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

        itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
        pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
        dayString.add(itemvalue);

    }
}

private int getMaxP() {
    int maxP;
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
    }
    maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return maxP;
}
```

}

error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.cogneesol.mycalendar, PID: 18708
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this inside if condition

```
v = convertView;
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
```

problem is might be in  `dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);`, you `v` can be `null` if `convertView` is `null`

or use `convertView.findViewById` instead of `v.findViewById`

Comment: thank you ravi ... now its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove your v variable and instead of it, use convertView